# why I cannot store derived class in base-typed std:vector?

Tags: c++

I know this may be a very simple question, But it really made me confused several days. I try to store derived class in a standard std:vector which stores base class type. 
If I make the base(father) class to be pure virtual class. I cannot store derived class in the vector. 
If I implement the base(father) class's getName() method. I can build successfully. But when iteratoring the vector. it lose the polymorphism...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class father{
public:
    //virtual string getName() = 0; //If uncomment here. push_back(c1) will induce build error.
    virtual string getName(){ return "father";}
};

class child1 : public father{
public:
    virtual string getName(){
        return "child1";
    }
};

class child2 : public father{
public:
    virtual string getName(){
        return "child2";
    }
};

class child3 : public father{
public:
    virtual string getName(){
        return "child3";
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    child1 c1;
    child2 c2;
    child3 c3;

    cout<< "c1  " << sizeof(c1) << endl;
    cout<< "c2  " << sizeof(c2) << endl;
    cout<< "c3  " << sizeof(c3) << endl;

    vector<father> v;
    v.push_back(c1); //build error if Father is pure virtual class
    v.push_back(c2); //build error
    v.push_back(c3); //build error

    for(std::vector<father>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "I'm " << it->getName() << endl; //lose polymorphism
    }
    return 0;
}
```

summary two questions:
1. why define base(father) class as pure virtual class. I cannot store derived class in vector ?
2. why when I get class from the vector again. it lose polymorphism ?

Thanks in advance for any help. Really appreciate that!

Comment: In your container, use pointers to the base class.

Comment: thank you to everyone for your help! I just first time heard the terminology "slicing", and I now know it! Thank you all again very much!

Answer (score 1):

That is because in C++, the vector stores `father`, which is an object in itself. In other languages like Java, you'd implicitly store a reference to the original object, the child.

When the `father` object stored inside of the vector is constructed, it *slices* the object copying from.

If you want something similar in C++ than in Java, use:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<father>> v;
```

Comment: Although one should make sure that shared ownership is actually needed before using `shared_ptr`.

Comment: If I store the pointer of object in the vector can I get them out in another thread?

Comment: @lancelot Yes, but use mutexes when necessary. Multi-threading can be tricky, especially when you are coming from a different environment which supports multi-threading with other idioms.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! You're really supportive!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. why define base(father) class as pure virtual class. I cannot store derived class in vector ?

You declared a vector of `father`, and if `father` is an abstrcat class, it can't be instantiated. Even if you put the instance of `child` into it, it will be copied(sliced) as `father`.

> 2. why when I get class from the vector again. it lose polymorphism ?

If you want keep the polymorphism, you must access the object by pointer or reference. In your case, it's better to use smart pointer rather than raw pointer, such as:

```
vector<shared_ptr<father>> v;
v.push_back(new child1);
v.push_back(new child2);
v.push_back(new child3);

for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "I'm " << (*it)->getName() << endl;
}
```